# Magento customer account navigation missing from left column

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, xml, local.xml

I have a issue where my customer account navigation is missing from the left column in the account area.

In my customer.xml file:

```
<customer_account translate="label">
    <label>Customer My Account (All Pages)</label>
    <!--remove name="catalog.compare.sidebar"/>
    <remove name="sale.reorder.sidebar"/-->
    <!-- Mage_Customer -->
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>

    <reference name="content">
        <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="my.account.wrapper" translate="label">
            <label>My Account Wrapper</label>
            <action method="setElementClass"><value>my-account</value></action>
        </block>
    </reference>

    <reference name="left">
        <block type="customer/account_navigation" name="customer_account_navigation" before="-" template="customer/account/navigation.phtml">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>account</name><path>customer/account/</path><label>Account Dashboard</label></action>
            <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>account_edit</name><path>customer/account/edit/</path><label>Account Information</label></action>
            <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>address_book</name><path>customer/address/</path><label>Address Book</label></action>
        </block>
        <block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" name="cart_sidebar" template="checkout/cart/sidebar.phtml">
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>simple</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
        </block>
        <block type="catalog/product_compare_sidebar" name="catalog.compare.sidebar" template="catalog/product/compare/sidebar.phtml"/>
        <remove name="tags_popular"/>

    </reference>
</customer_account>
```

When I change `<reference name="left">` to `<reference name="content">` the navigation is being displayed in the content column therefore I belive it has something to do with the reference name "left" element.

In my 2column-left.phtml file I got this:

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('head') ?>
</head>

<body<?php echo $this->getBodyClass()?' class="'.$this->getBodyClass().'"':'' ?>>

<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('after_body_start') ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('header') ?>

<div class="container b30 t30">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_notices') ?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') ?>

    <div class="row">
        <aside class="col-md-3">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('left') ?>
        </aside>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <?php

                $yourUrlKey = 'tpd';
                $yourUrlKey2 = 'tdp-faq';
                $cmsPageUrlKey = Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier();
                    
                if($yourUrlKey == $cmsPageUrlKey || $yourUrlKey2 == $cmsPageUrlKey) { ?>
                    
                    <div class="three-buttons mB20">
                        <a class="button green mR20" href="/safety-data/">Safety Data</a> <a class="button green mR20 tpd" href="/tpd/">TOBACCO PRODUCTS DIRECTIVE</a> <a class="button green mR20 faq" href="/tdp-faq/">FAQs</a> <a class="button green" target="_blank" href="https://www.domain.com/new_order_form.xlsx">Download Our Order Form</a>
                    </div>
                    
                <?php } ?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>
            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer') ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('before_body_end') ?>
<?php echo $this->getAbsoluteFooter() ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found what the problem was. I only took over from someone else and only getting my head around the system.

The problem was, there was a

```
<layout version="1.0">
<default><remove name="left"/></default>
```

element in one of the custom modules written by someone. Removing the

```
<remove name="left"/>
```

fixed my problem.

Answer (score 2):

As you got solution But I want to give some suggestion,

As you found that issue with `<remove name="left"/>`

because this thing remove from `default` handler,

If you remove something in `default` handler then it will never get loaded again by any other handler.

If you `remove` any block from handler then you cannot re load that block

If you want to load it again that block in that particular block then always use `unset`.

And specially if you are developing an extension then don't use `remove` always use `unset` as a best practice

Comment: Yes, great advice. Whoever have developed the module, included the `<remove name="left">` in the `default` handler so whatever I have tried didn't work as it was simply deleted and couldn't find where it was. I have used `unset` instead of `remove` now. Thanks for advice.

Comment: You are always welcome @GrzegorzWisniewski :)

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below screenshot

[image]

I think you might be miss the "addBodyClass" method in 'customer.xml'

```
    <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addBodyClass"><class>customer-account</class></action>
   <reference>
```

Please do the changes accordingly and remove the cache session after modify the layout file.

Comment: Hi there! I did exactly what you have mentioned but this has not solve the issue. Any other suggestions?

Comment: ok please comment the code in between the  div i.e <div class="col-md-9"> and check the same. screenshot: http://prntscr.com/f1uhvw

Comment: Only left <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>    in the <div class="col-md-9"> but it has not solve the problem